# Dev loop0 unable to read RDB block 8

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

When I boot on my computer, I receive this error: `Dev loop0 unable to read RDB block 8`.
Then, I can't use the keyboard to launch the shell or anything else. All the computer is block during the boot, and nothing can be done to unlock that (I've to restart manually the computer).

I can launch the `Xubuntu 22.04` via the recovery mode, but after that, if I restart, I've always the problem.

I already update my system, reinstall `snapd` but that not work.

There is some information: My computer use a dual boot `Windows - Xubuntu 22.04`. I did an update before shutting down my computer, then, after the update, I can't boot on it because of this error.